# Import XMI Deletes Sequences

Tags: enterprise-architect

I import XMI of a package hierarchy to a local model, and it's successfully imported.

When I import the same XMI to a shared model (Oracle DB), all the sequences and messages in sequence diagrams are deleted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That is a known issue. (search "version control" + "sequence diagram" in the EA forum)

Using instances instead of classifiers in sequence diagrams will to some degree solve that issue.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean to use instances instead of links,  or instances instead of lifelines?

Comment: It's not really an issue per se. The issue is that EA does not enforce to use instances and permits the use of classes. And using instances will solve the problem at 100%. It's hidden somewhere in the help that you need to do that.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, Thanks. But my Sequence diagrams do not contain links. They contain instances of components. Any ideas?

Comment: In that case you should report a bug. I would not see a difference between component and class instances. The issue Geert mentions is explicitly if you use element links instead of instances.

Answer (score 1):

An XMI representation of a model contains information on the elements in the exported package, and their connectors. Structurally, however, the connectors are not stored within the package in EA's data model, so EA simply writes into the XMI file every connector that connects any of the elements to anything else, whether or not the element at the other end of the connector is in scope.

On the other hand, a connector is by definition connected at both ends -- you cannot create a connector in EA that is only connected to an element at one end. This means that each connector is written to the XMI file with a reference to both its elements.

If both elements are in the scope of the XMI export (in the same package tree), then all's well. But if only one of them is, EA is not able to recreate the connector on import -- only one element is present in the XMI file. When this occurs, EA will ignore the offending connector.

The exception to this is if the element which is missing from the XMI file happens to be in the model already. In that case, EA will recreate the connector. I think this might be what you're seeing in your "local" model.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. If there are connectors that points to elements outside of the exported package, there must be a problem in empty local model just like in Oracle model. However, in my case the import succeed in local model and fails in Oracle. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With Enterprise Architect v.13 I managed to get rid of the trouble;
Supposing that your sequences has Lifelines with Instance Classifier set to the Class/Component that you would like to use in our sequence:

1. Right Click on the Package that you would like to Export
2. Go to Package Baseline and create New Baseline for the package
3. Once Baseline is shown, from the "Baseline" choose "Export File"
4. Save it as XMI File
5. Import XMI file in the other EAP Project.

I compared the XMI file generated from a Baseline with an XMI generated by clicking on the option "Import/Export" and they have differences... it seems like that the Exported XMI of the Baseline contains full information of the model (included root nodes), thus I think the import process might resolve each link to objects that are not hold in the same package...